# How to get notified when enumerateLinesUsingBlock is completed

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, block, enumerate

Is there any way to notify when a `enumerateLinesUsingBlock` is completed? Please check below code. I am calling `createFastSearchData` method with chunk by chunk data in a while loop and inside that taking each lines and processing it. In while condition I am checking the length of the main string and I want to continue untill it completes the total length. So I want to make sure that `enumerateLinesUsingBlock` is completed before the while loop trigger again.

```
while(<checking the length of the mainstring>){
   [self createFastSearchData:string];
}


- (void)createFastSearchData:(NSString *)newChunk{
     [newChunk enumerateLinesUsingBlock:^(NSString * line, BOOL * stop)
         {}];
}
```

**Added:**

I am working with blocks and finding difficulty to understand the actual flow. Please check the below code. I want to call `fetchCSVData` method by passing different values in an array `filesToBeFetchedWhat`. I want to make sure that, `fetchCSVData` should not overlap.  How can I do that? Please help

```
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        @autoreleasepool {
            for (int i = 0; i < filesToBeFetched.count; i++) {
                [applicationDelegate fetchCSVData:[filesToBeFetched objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
        }
        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Fetching is done *********************");
        });
    });
```

Comment: The `enumerate...UsingBlock` methods don't work asynchronously.

Comment: So you mean, it won't come back to while condition before completing the enumeration?

Comment: Yes, exactly, prove it be inserting `NSLog` lines.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of the question:

All `enumerate...UsingBlock` methods don't work asynchronously.

Regarding the added part:

Assuming `fetchCSVData` works also synchronously, that's the preferred way to process the data

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    @autoreleasepool {
       for (int i = 0; i < filesToBeFetched.count; i++) {
          [applicationDelegate fetchCSVData:[filesToBeFetched objectAtIndex:i]];
          dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Fetching is done *********************");
          });
       }
    }
});
```